# React Navigation Error Does not Fire when pressed

Tags: reactjs, navigation

Hi Guys I am trying to navigate between screens (not home screen)

I get an error that says the this.props.navigation is undefined. However, I have defined it. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you component with withNavigation() like below:

```
withNavigation(component);
```